# Remove (Click) Dropdown Functionality From Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, menu, onclick

I'm customizing a theme for a client and trying to find a way to remove the dropdown functionality of the main navigation links. When you click on a top-level link, the menu closes (or opens). I'm not sure why they built this into the theme as I think it's very confusing to the user, not to mention doesn't work properly on mobile. I really need the menus to open on hover but not onclick.

I believe this is being done using a combination of CSS3 and Javascript (https://github.com/viljamis/responsive-nav.js). There's probably a simple solution by just editing the responsive-nav.js. But I'm not a javascript coder. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

The site is here: http://www.gatewayfitnesscenter.com

Code I believe controls this: http://gatewayfitnesscenter.com/wp-content/themes/westand/scripts/frontend/responsive-nav.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your theme's `scripts/frontend/functions.js`, locate this block of code (two lines after "`//menu toggle`"):

```
jQuery("#menus  li.sub-icon > a") .click(function(){
    jQuery(this).next().toggle(200);
    return false;
});
```

That is the click handler so go ahead and remove it and you should be good!

Comment: You are amazing! Thanks so much for chiming in at this late hour. That worked perfectly. :)

Answer (score 0):

OK, so it turns out this will be a fairly easy CSS tweak to get what you want. Open the style.css file for your "westland" theme. Now, search for `.navigation ul li:hover > ul {`. The first line after that is `visibility: visible;`. Either delete that line or comment it out and save the file. If you really want to avoid unnecessary work in the browser, delete/comment the entire block within. I've included the entire block below after commenting it out.

```
.navigation ul li:hover > ul {
    /*
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    -o-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
    */
}
```

That should prevent hovering over those menus from showing the sub-menu.

Comment: Thanks ventaur for the quick answer. Unfortunately it didn't do the trick. I suppose it's being called somewhere else. Either way, you rock for jumping and providing an answer!

Comment: I wondered what translateY(0) was. I've never come across it or used it before. I will try this and let you know. Thanks SO much!

Comment: Actually, that just got rid of the hover effect. What I want to do is get rid of the click effect. When someone hovers over the menu, I want them to find the submenus. But when they click on a top-level menu, I don't want the submenus to disappear (like it does now). Hope that makes sense.

Comment: translateY(0) is telling modern browsers (CSS3) to move the entire sub-menu to the y-coordinate of 0. It starts out 20 pixels down, so when you hover the mouse over the menu, the sub-menu will move from 20 pixels down back up to 0. This gives it that ever-so slight effect of the sub-menu sliding up while at the same time becoming visible.

Comment: Awesome, I definitely learned something new tonight. I'm going to have to play around with that now and add it to my arsenal. :)

Comment: Ah, my misunderstanding. I'll poke around tomorrow and see if I can spot where responseNav is being called from. I see it has some options that may be being overridden by the theme (gotta find it). My guess is one of the theme's JS or HTML files is calling responsiveNav with the option ```closeOnNavClick``` set to true instead of false.

Comment: Awesome, I'll play around with it some more tonight. I remember seeing that somewhere in the responsive-nav.js. Thanks so much for helping me out. I love this community!